# How to open recomplyed PDF file at the same place

Tags: pdf, kile, okular

I am writing articles using kile. The process goes on like this: I make some changes, then I comply using quickbuild and look at the result, then I make changes again, and so on.

Now, when I use quick build, every time new Okular window is opened and I have to scroll down for the place where the changes are made. The document has about 20 pages, and it is rather annoying having to look for the corrections every time.

Is it possible to  make  Okular somehow capture the place where I looked at in the document?

I have this problem only on my laptop with win 7. On my office PC a new Okular window would open after each quick build, and the old window would hold the place where I was looking but reload the document. This would be perfectly fine for me too, but I don't know how to get it.

Sorry if a similar question has already been asked, I have not found it.

Comment: Why do you set it up so it opens a new view for each compile?

Comment: @cfr I did not set it up... Do you know how can I change this?

Comment: Well, it might be a Windows thing. It doesn't do that on Linux. I think what I do is not use Quick Build, although you could configure Quick Build if you wanted. I *just* typeset. I don't do anything to trigger a view. Then in Okular, I set the viewer to reload the PDF when the file changes. This does mean that the first time I compile, I need to also open the PDF view. But then I just leave that one view open and compile to see the changes. Does that make sense?

Comment: There are also different ways of triggering viewers such as Okular. In settings > Tools > Build > ViewPDF, do you have `Okular Unique` as well as `Okular`? Switching between these determines whether a new viewer will be opened or the old one reused, I think.

Comment: @cfr Thanks! Changing Okular Unique to Okular helped. Somehow Okular doesn't update the file automatically, like on linux machine, but pressing F5 solves the issue.

Comment: Hmmm.... That's a shame. I know Windows handles files etc. rather differently, so I maybe that's an unavoidable limitation. In Okular's settings, do you have an option to automatically reload on file change?

Comment: @cfr Yes, and it is ticked. In any case, pressing one more key isn't a big deal )

Comment: OK, well, I'm glad it helps, anyway, even if it doesn't work quite as perfectly as it does for me. (I expect it will now fail horribly that I've said that :(.)